# Any limitations of app launchEvent

Tags: nativescript

I've got

`app.on(app.launchEvent, function (args)
{
        alert({title: "ERROR", message: "test", okButtonText: "Close"});
}`

The alert doesn't display.

Are there limitations as to what can be done within that callback.

Looks like the Android context is not set up at this time and causes problems with other plug-ins also.

Answer (score 0):

lauchEvent must be defined before `application.start(...);` in app.js file, if it's after `start` line it won't fire and same if it's inside other files it won't fire as that lauchEvent is already over or quite possible that dialog is skipped too as it's discarded while moving over to pages

Comment: It's before application.start();

Comment: so only explanation is that dialog is fired and works and is closed at same time because of navigation to mainModule, as dialog don't stop execution of code so code after that still continue